# facebook rauth python friendslist is not available

Tags: python, facebook

I have the code fragment from

https://github.com/litl/rauth/blob/master/examples/facebook/facebook.py

```
def authorized():
    # check to make sure the user authorized the request
    if not 'code' in request.args:
        flash('You did not authorize the request')
        return redirect(url_for('index'))

    # make a request for the access token credentials using code
    redirect_uri = url_for('authorized', _external=True)
    data = dict(code=request.args['code'], redirect_uri=redirect_uri)

    session = facebook.get_auth_session(data=data)

    # the "me" response
    me = session.get('me').json()

    User.get_or_create(me['username'], me['id'])

#print(me['first_name'])
#flash('Logged in as ' + me['name'])
    flash('Logged in as ' + me['name'])
    for key, value in me.iteritems():
    print key, value
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

The main problem is that the hash "me" doesn't contain any key corresponding key for friendslist. But in the graph explorer

```
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=xxxxxxxfields%3Dfriendlists
```

I can get the friendslist in the list that pops up while clicking the "+" sign and by clicking submit I can get the list of friends. Hence how can I get the friendslist using rauth API?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Uh I got it this is:

```
friends = session.get('<id>/friends').json();
```